# Pass argument to InstallScript Custom Action

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have BASIC MSI project in InstallShield 2015

I have a setup dialog with Next and Back buttons, both have the same event, an InstallScript Custom Action with immediate execution.
Now is there a way that the CA will know what triggers it, meaning if it’s the Next or Back button ?
Should I used CustomActionData for that ? If yes is there a dummies guide how to implement it ?

Comment: CustomActionData is only used in deferred actions (those are never part of your UI) so it doesn't help here. Use a property like jbudreau describes, or use multiple functions in multiple separate immediate actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be for your Next and Back buttons to have a new ControlEvent added to their button clicks that set a property to some value right before calling your CA (i.e. [ButtonClicked] set to "Next" or "Back"). Then, your CA reads the value and acts appropriately.